# Solar panel voltage reducing by adding cellophane

Tags: voltage, solar-cells, intensity, attenuation

For a physics report, I am aiming to answer the question **How does the power output of a solar cell vary with the thickness of cling wrap laid over it?**

I got a negative relationship between voltage and thickness of cellophane (see the graph, values and setup here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1H4z.jpg)

While the results make sense to me, I am struggling to find the equation/theory that explains this. Does anyone know?

Comment: This is almost certainly optical absorption in the cellophane. Take a look at the Beer Lambert law, you should be able to determine the absorption coefficient if you can estimate the layer thickness      https://www.edinst.com/blog/the-beer-lambert-law/